# Cannot rebase after fetch. Fetch says `fatal: could not fetch SHA from promisor remote`

Tags: git

I get the following message after running `git fetch`:
`fatal: could not fetch SHA from promisor remote`

This, somehow, messes everything up. I cannot rebase after this. Running `git rebase` returns the same error but puts me in a weird state where I cannot rebase any further.

The SHA is not associated with any submodule nor was there any commit where the super-project was committed and the associated submodule(s) was/were not.

I use partial clones. I don't know if that is somehow messing things up. Has been working flawlessly till the end of last year though.

Have tried every combination of arguments with `git fetch` like `--refetch --auto-gc -pP` and `--force --tags`. Nothing helps. Once I nuke the existing local copy and clone again, it works nicely again and after a few days it does the same thing. I have a lot of branches to track and recloning every time takes a lot of time.

UPDATE:
Observed the same error when merging.

```
> git fetch
fatal: remote error: upload-pack: not our ref SHA
fatal: could not fetch SHA from promisor remote

> git merge origin/BRANCH
fatal: remote error: upload-pack: not our ref SHA1
error: Could not read SHA1
fatal: remote error: upload-pack: not our ref SHA2
error: Could not read SHA2
fatal: remote error: upload-pack: not our ref SHA3
fatal: could not fetch SHA3 from promisor remote
```

Does not even enter into the merge mode.

Comment: Where is the `Heah`? are you in `Detached` head?

Comment: The superproject HEAD is pointing to the appropriate branch. The submodules are pointing to the main branches.

Answer (score 1):

> Has been working flawlessly till the end of last year though.

That error message is from [`promisor-remote.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blame/d9d677b2d8cc5f70499db04e633ba7a400f64cbf/promisor-remote.c#L265), introduced in Git v2.39.0-rc0 ([commit 301f1e3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/301f1e3ac1531dc3a15064a06b24fa98f02a3b78))

That means you can check if the same `fetch` work with Git 2.38.x instead of the current latest 2.39.x.

Comment: I will try going back to the previous version and see if I see a difference.

Comment: Also discussed in https://public-inbox.org/git/CAM9q8UoE5OGLkZ7MduXqWjxyGV7xNFBXsEbaYG1H61zZ9AO_XA@mail.gmail.com/T/#u